# Earth science database

Tags: database-design

My aim is to collate various conclusions from different articles. I was wondering if anyone knows of a database (or program) that can do what I want.

What I'm looking for:
I have a lot of literature. Each source reconstructs the paleo-landscape using different proxies (ex, palynology, isotope data, sedimentology, etc). The proxies indicate several things. For example, (a) time period, (b) temperature, (c) non arboreal pollen, etc. And at times, these may indicate changes in the landscape (ex. increase in temperature causes sea ice to melt therefore sea level rise. This in turn will inundate the coast with water). And sometimes, there are ranges of years that span 1000's of years and within those ranges, oscilations of events (ex, oscillations of arid and cold climates within an overall wet and warm period). Add to this, I have research done on different scales: locally, regionally, and globally. And they are all interconnected.

So, I'm looking for a database or program that allows me to collate all the different research into one place, so that when I want to see relationships in one time span or year, i can have a quick overview of the different proxies and the conclusions that they may indicate. In addition, I'd like to visualize this in a graph with time as an axis. And finally, since my research is growing, i also want to be able to link the information to the literature from which I retrieved the conclusions.

I've looked online. Asked around. I've worked with 2 programs (PAST and Tillia) and do a little of what i want, but they require raw data. I don't want that, i only want to work with my summaries of the articles. I'm a little familiar with simple database building, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it's out there. Or maybe I'm asking too much.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about Wikipedia

Comment: I don't think you're really looking for a particular database system, but rather a specialised Earth science software which probably does use a database system and a particular schema to store its data, although that's not really the main point, and could be using any of a number of different database systems (MariaDB, PostgreSQL etc). Therefore, you'd probably have more luck asking in a different forum, perhaps somewhere dedicated to Earth science software or similar.